# Is it possible to rebind a socket that is already bound?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

This is what i want to do:

```
+--------+                          +--------+
|        |                          |        |
| Server |---+                  +---| Client |
|        |   |                  |   |        |
+--------+   |                  |   +--------+
             |                  |
+--------+   |   +--------+     |   +--------+
|        |   |   |        |     |   |        |
| Server |---+---+  Proxy +-----+---+ Client |
|        |   |   |        |     |   |        |
+--------+   |   +--------+     |   +--------+
             |                  |
+--------+   |                  |   +--------+
|        |   |                  |   |        |
| Server |---+                  +---| Client |
|        |                          |        |
+--------+                          +--------+
```

The servers will connect to the proxy server, then clients will connect the proxy server and request to get redirected to one of the connected servers. e.g. Client1 wants to get redirected to Server3. My problem is, is that once a client is connected, i want to rebound it to another Server. You cannot rebound a socket once it is bound. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Do you mean have the Proxy just broker the connection, but then have the clients directly connect to any given server? Not sure what you're after here...

Comment: The clients connect to the proxy, then i want the proxy to be able to connect the client to a server. The servers only connect to the proxy to relay information about the server, like which port the server is running on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the assumptions of the socket API, you are correct, a connection remains bound until it is closed.

Your two options are

1. Write a meta-protocol in the client and server to have a virtual connection that uses a multiplicity of sockets to simulate a persistent connection spanning multiple servers (hard)
2. Have a smart proxy that terminates a client socket and connects to servers as needed and pretends that it isn't there to the other end points (less hard or already done for you depending on your proxy service.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for always having the Proxy <-> Client connection up. If there is a need to connect to another server, only shut down the Proxy <-> Server1 connection and create another one Proxy <-> Server2. This way, the client won't have to disconnect and the re-connection to another server will be seamless.